# Azure Logic App issue when Insert into SQL Table

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm running LogicApp to get data from a REST API and inserting it into a SQL Table. I'm looping through a nested **For Each** to INSERT nested JSON Arrays into the table.

I Placed the SQL Insert in the inner most Loop.

I'm getting a time out error at the SQL Insert step for some records only error:

{
  "statusCode": 429,
  "message": "Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 1 seconds."
}

Comment: The "Rate Limit exceeded" error means that you hit the limit of API calls for the SQL Server connector.check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#special-throttling-limits). Consider take a try to reduce the API calls from your app to the SQL Server connector. You could patch less records (e.g. 50 records) to your SQL table once time, and then patch the next 50 records, etc.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you're saying, the problem is happening when the data gets inserted at the SQL Insert block ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881776/azure-logic-app-with-azure-blob-storage-action-getting-429-statuscode-error/68301976#68301976